# Water spills from kitchen seep to downstairs

Tags: electrical, water

Noticed some water in basement in the middle of the floor. I looks to be seepage from a water spill in the kitchen from earlier (water must have gone further back under the fridge than what was cleaned up with a towel).

It has dried enough on the ceiling that I couldn't pinpoint exactly where it seeped through; however based on the floor spot and the spill location above, it came down near one of the pot lights. The lights are not live yet; however, I don't want to have to worry about this for any future spills that aren't fully soaked up.

The upstairs is old hardwood. The subfloor is planks (not plywood).

Is there anything from below I can do? Or a seleant for the hardwood?  Obviously the easiest solution is to clean up all of the spill, but looking for a more thorough solution. Ideas?

Comment: Are you concerned about electrical problems or just sealing?

Comment: Main concern electrical. We are not finishing the ceiling in the basement so no worries about damage there.

Comment: With your statement, how can we give advice? Wood floors above , can lights below ???  Seal the upper floor but if you don’t there will probably be no difference even in multi level structures.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry if my question is confusing. I want to prevent water spills from getting to electrical components of the pot light. I don't know what sealant with the hardwood would work and keep/improve the floor. I didn't know if the fix was going to require me to pull up the wood and add a barrier. If it was, I was curious if there was a way that I could address the issue from below and not have to pull up the wood.